# Combining two functions to apply them to the same input

Tags: haskell, text, predicate

I'm new to Haskell and I'm still getting my head around it. I'm trying to combine two functions (`isMark` and `isAlpha` from [Data.Char](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html) module in `base` package) as a first argument to [Data.Text.filter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:filter) function. What I've tried so far was:

```
import qualified Data.Char as C
import qualified Data.Text as T
import           Data.Text (Text)

strippedInput :: Text -> Text
strippedInput input = T.filter (C.isMark || C.isAlpha) input
```

which doesn't work, or

```
strippedInput input = T.filter (C.isMark . C.isAlpha) input
```

but obviously it doesn't work either, as the type of `C.isAlpha` is `Char -> Bool` which then becomes an input to `C.isMark` which is also of type `Char -> Bool` so types don't match.

I'd like to achieve the "`C.isMark` OR `C.isAlpha`" logic in the predicate but because of my very limited knowledge I've run out of ideas on how to search for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest is to make use of a *lambda-expression*:

```
strippedInput :: Text -> Text
strippedInput input = T.filter (\x -> C.isMark x || C.isAlpha x) input
```

You can furthermore make use of the fact that a function is an applicative functor, and thus work with:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

strippedInput :: Text -> Text
strippedInput input = T.filter (liftA2 (||) C.isMark C.isAlpha) input
```

Comment: Sorry, obviously I meant "OR", not "AND". I'll edit my question. Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful and clear!

Comment: If you find yourself doing this a lot, it's kinda neat IMO to define `(<||>) = liftA2 (||)`, so that you can write `strippedInput = T.filter (C.isMark <||> C.isAlpha)`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is perfectly right. Perhaps I would like to use the applicative operator though;

```
strippedInput = T.filter $ (||) <$> C.isMark <*> C.isAlpha
```

However the problem with `liftA2` is, as depicted by the name, it is hardwired only to two parameter functions and yes, it is OK for this question. Yet... Haskell provides a more reasonable *general* abstraction for this job. It's basically called the function monad that is mostly generalized as the Reader monad by adding some utility functions and transformer abilities. However for simplicity we can try the function monad here.

Function/Reader monad is used to chain up not only two but indefinite number of functions (each taking two parameters) in which case the first parameter is fed by the previous function result and the second by a common read only state (in this case it is the `input`)

So the answer to this question could also be like

```
strippedInput = T.filter (C.isMark >>= (\b c -> b || C.isAlpha c) >>= return)
```

However since the `Data.Char` package is full of `isThis`, `isThat` type of checks we can show how one may extend this approach.

```
strippedInput = T.filter (C.isMark >>= (\b c -> b || C.isAlpha  c)
                                   >>= (\b c -> b || C.isSymbol c)
                                    .
                                    .
                                   >>= return)
```

and.. nobody stops you to make a comparison function such as

```
orWith f      = \b c -> b || f c
strippedInput = T.filter $ C.isMark >>= orWith C.isAlpha
                                    >>= orWith C.isSymbol
                                     .
                                     .
                                    >>= return
```

Comment: Whoa that looks complicated from the beginner's perspective. I'll try to delve into monads next. Thanks for directions!